# Terraform Apply Error: Code="InvalidResourceName" Message="Resource name is invalid" When creating VPN-GW Module

Tags: terraform, vpn, terraform-provider-azure

I'm receiving the following error when executing the Terraform Apply Command.

```
│ Error: Creating/Updating Virtual Network Gateway: (Name "VPN-GW-HUB-dev" / Resource Group "RG-HUB-dev"): network.VirtualNetworkGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceName" Message="Resource name  is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must end with a word character or with '_'. The name may contain word characters or '.', '-', '_'." Details=[]
│ 
│   with module.MOD-VPN-GW.azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.vpngw,
│   on Modules/10.VPN-GW/main.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpngw":
│   31: resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpngw" {
```

**What was I trying to do?**

My Terraform code creates a complete Hub-and-Spoke infrastructure in Azure. It worked very well until I decided to modularise the VPN GW part.

My Terraform code structure is the usual format:

```
--Modules/{module-name}/main.tf
--main.tf
```

So within the {module-name} - I have a folder called:

```
10.VPN-GW\main.tf
```

**What have I tried?**

Well, I have tried to reformat the code, I double checked it against all other modules that worked OK. I have NO idea why this error is happening, and it has been 3 days now non stop debugging this.

The module file is here:

```
#------------------------------
# VPN GW MODULE FILE - ALso contains GW SUBNET
#-------------------------------

resource "azurerm_subnet" "gwSubnet" {
  name                 =    var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  =    var.subnet_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name =    var.subnet_virtual_network_name
  address_prefixes     =    var.subnet_address_prefixes

}

variable "subnet_name" {
    type = string
}

variable "subnet_resource_group_name" {
    type = string
}

variable "subnet_virtual_network_name" {
    type = string
}

variable "subnet_address_prefixes" {
    type = list(string)
}


output "outSubnetIDVPNGW" {
    value = azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id
}
 

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpngw" {
  name                = "${var.vpn-gw-name}"
  location            = "${var.vpn-gw-location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.vpngw_resource_group_name}"

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  
  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.ip_configuration_name}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${var.ip_configuration_public_ip_address_id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id
  }

    vpn_client_configuration {
        address_space = "${var.vpn_client_configuration_address_space}"

        root_certificate {
        name = "${var.root_certificate_name}"
        public_cert_data = "${var.cert}"
    }

    revoked_certificate {
      name       = "${var.revoked_certificate_name}"
      thumbprint = "${var.revoked_certificate_thumbprint}"
    }
  }
}

variable "vpn-gw-name" {
    type = string
    //default = ""
}

variable "vpn-gw-location" {
    //default = ""
    type = string
}

variable "vpngw_resource_group_name" {
    default = ""
}

variable "ip_configuration_name" {
    default = ""
}

variable "ip_configuration_public_ip_address_id" {
    default = ""
}

/*
variable "ip_configuration_private_ip_address_allocation" {
    //default = ""
   // type = string
}
*/

variable "vpn_client_configuration_address_space" {
    default = []
}

variable "root_certificate_name" {
    default = ""
}

variable "cert" {  
    default = ""
}

variable "revoked_certificate_name" {
  default = ""
}

variable "revoked_certificate_thumbprint" {
    default = ""
}

variable "ip_configuration" {
    type = map(string)
}


variable "vpn_client_configuration" {
  type = object({
    address_space           = list(string)
    root_certificate        = map(string)
    revoked_certificate     = map(string)
  })
} 

/*
variable "revoked_certificate" {
  type = map(string)
}
*/
```

The main.tf file -- that calls each module, is given below - (I'm only adding the snippet for the part causing the error) - i.e. creation of the VPN GW

```
#-----------------------------------------
# Create GW SUBNET & VPN GW
#-----------------------------------------

module "MOD-VPN-GW" {
  source              = "./Modules/10.VPN-GW"

  subnet_name                 = "GatewaySubnet"
  subnet_resource_group_name  = "RG-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  subnet_virtual_network_name =  "VNET-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  subnet_address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/27"]

  vpn-gw-name                 = "VPN-GW-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  vpn-gw-location               = "westeurope"
  vpngw_resource_group_name   = "RG-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  
  ip_configuration = {
    name        = "VNetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id                    = "${module.MOD-VPNGW-PIP.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation  = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                   = module.MOD-VPN-GW.outSubnetIDVPNGW
  }

  vpn_client_configuration = {
    address_space = ["172.16.10.0/24"]

    root_certificate = {
      name = "dev.vpn.macos.com"
      public_cert_data  = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.akv-certificate.certificate_data_base64

    }

    revoked_certificate  = {
      name       = "Verizon-Global-Root-CA"
      thumbprint = "912198EEF23DCAC40939312FEE97DD560BAE49B1"
    }
  }

   depends_on = [
     module.MOD-RG-HUB, module.MOD-VNET-HUB, azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.label-vm-spoke-01
  ]

}
```

**What did I search for?**

I cannot seem to find this particular error code in a google search. Its not telling me that name given to my VPN GW is incorrect - its giving me the name (in the error message) and telling me that there is no name given. Which is odd. Or have I misunderstood the error message?

The terraform init command succeeds.
The terraform validate command succeeds.
The terraform plan command succeeds.

This fails when applying

Comment: I think it can be any of the errors mentioned, it could happen the name is longer than 80 characters or has some invalid characters. What does `var.environmentCode` resolve to? I.e., does it contain any characters not allowed or does it make the `vpn-gw-name` longer than 80 characters?

Comment: No. It just contains the name i.e. VPN-GW-HUB or whatever the nomenclature is.

Comment: So the value of the variable `var.environmentCode` is an empty string?

Comment: No. Not all... The name given is: "VPN-GW-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"

Comment: The "VPN-GW-HUB-${var.environmentCode}" = VPN-GW-HUB-dev - so by all means, the string is not at all empty

Comment: Ok, so then I see one thing that could be problematic from Terraform's standpoint: `subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id` is defined like this in the GW module. But then, you are trying to pass another value to it with `subnet_id  = module.MOD-VPN-GW.outSubnetIDVPNGW`. I think the first step would be to drop the latter when calling the GW module as there is no `subnet_id` variable defined for the GW module and it's not needed as you already are getting the subnet ID as an attribute from the `azurerm_subnet ` resource.

Comment: Hi Marko. I'm not at all sure I understand your point, but what is interesting is that I feel that the root cause is related to subnet ID. So how do I declare the subnet_id within the resource declaration in the VPN module??

Comment: Think of modules as functions in programming: you would provide only those values which are required for the function to produce a required result. The `ip_configuration` block already has the value for the `subnet_id` populated with the output provided when the `azurerm_subnet` resource is created, which is `azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id`. This means there is no need to provide anything else for that value.

Comment: So the ip_configuration block should be removed from Module file? Is that right? I removed it from the module,and I get the following error:  At least 1 "ip_configuration" blocks are required.

Comment: No, not from the VPN GW module but from the root module, i.e., the code calling the VPN GW module.

Comment: But the root module knows the subnet_id. It needs to give the VPN module the subnet_id. If I remove it, how will the VPN module receive the subnet ID?

Comment: I removed the GW-SUBNET from the VPN GW Module into its own module - hence, there's no way to get the subnet_id into the VPN _GW module other than through the root module. You see the issue?

Comment: Can you update the question then? Right now it seems like the GW Subnet is a part of the VPN GW module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue between the `root` module and the `VPN GW` module. The way that modules in Terraform work is similar to functions in other programming languages: they require certain input variables which are then replaced by the values provided to them. More about modules in [1].

To refactor this code, I would do the following in the `root` module:

```
  source = "./Modules/10.VPN-GW"

  subnet_name                 = "GatewaySubnet"
  subnet_resource_group_name  = "RG-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  subnet_virtual_network_name = "VNET-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  subnet_address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/27"]

  vpn-gw-name               = "VPN-GW-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"
  vpn-gw-location           = "westeurope"
  vpngw_resource_group_name = "RG-HUB-${var.environmentCode}"

  ip_configuration_name                 = "VNetGatewayConfig"
  ip_configuration_public_ip_address_id = module.MOD-VPNGW-PIP.id

  vpn_client_configuration_address_space = ["172.16.10.0/24"]
  root_certificate_name                  = "dev.vpn.macos.com"
  cert                                   = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.akv-certificate.certificate_data_base64

  revoked_certificate_name       = "Verizon-Global-Root-CA"
  revoked_certificate_thumbprint = "912198EEF23DCAC40939312FEE97DD560BAE49B1"

}
```

As you can see, the only change I did was to assign the values to variables that the `VPN GW` module requires. The way this works is when the module is called, it will be provided with values for the variables and it will know what to do with them. There is no need to define the same blocks in the calling (`root`) and called module (`VPN GW`). So, think of the `root` module as of a piece of code that invokes a function, something like:

```
MOD_VPN_GW(subnet_name, subnet_resource_group_name, subnet_virtual_network_name, subnet_address_prefixes, vpn-gw-name, vpn-gw-location, vpngw_resource_group_name, ip_configuration_name, ip_configuration_public_ip_address_id, vpn_client_configuration_address_space, root_certificate_name, cert, revoked_certificate_name, revoked_certificate_thumbprint)
```

As for your question about how the `subnet_id` will be accessible, that is the easy part. In the `VPN GW` module there is a resource block for `azurerm_subnet`:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "gwSubnet" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.subnet_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.subnet_virtual_network_name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}
```

One of the attributes that is provided by this resource after creation is the subnet ID [2].That means that you can assign the attribute value by referencing the resulting value using this syntax [3]:

```
<resource type>.<resource_name>.<attribute>
```

In your case that is:

```
azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id
```

This value is already referenced in the `subnet_id` argument of the `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` resource:

```
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gwSubnet.id
```

This means it is not required as one of the input variables by the module. The good thing is that the `VPN GW` module will know in which order to create resource as this is an implicit dependency.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet#id

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#references-to-resource-attributes

Comment: Thanks , but I get now an error:Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 436, in module "MOD-VPN-GW":
│  436: module "MOD-VPN-GW" {
│ 
│ The argument "vpn_client_configuration" is required, but no definition was found.
╵

Comment: Thanks Marko.. it worked. So I just erased the vpn_client_configuration definition - and all is good. Indeed, I will probably take a good look at the links you've sent . I'm eternally grateful